# Modelica: Can I use IncludeDirectory to specify an absolute path in Windows?

Tags: modelica, dymola

Sorry for the noob question. I am trying to learn how to integrate a C function in Modelica model. I am having trouble understanding how to specify the path to my external functions.

I created an external C function and saved in a different directory than my model directory or the working directory. I thought that using the IncludeDirectory annotation would allow me to refer to where that C function is located, but I can't get it to work.

```
impure function computeHeat "Modelica wrapper for an embedded C function controller"
input Real T;
input Real Tbar;
input Real Q;
output Real heat;
external "C"annotation(Include="#include<ComputeHeat.c>",IncludeDirectory="E:/temp/source_C");
end computeHeat;
```

When I tried to compile a demo example model, I got the following message.

Compiler message:

Compiling and linking the model (Visual C++).

dsmodel.c
dsmodel.c(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ComputeHeat.c': No such file or directory

Error generating Dymosim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IncludeDirectory should be an URI and only modelica-URIs are currently supported in Dymola.

So, store your function `computeHeat` in e.g. e:/temp/computeHeat.mo
And use `IncludeDirectory="modelica://computeHeat/source_C"`

In general I would assume `computeHeat` would be part of a package, `MyPackage`, stored as `e:/temp/MyPackage/package.mo` (and more files, e.g. computeHeat.mo).

In that case create `e:/temp/MyPackage/Resources/source_C` and use `IncludeDirectory="modelica://MyPackage/source_C"` The latter case is the recommended one, since you can copy `MyPackage` as a directory and the source follows.

Comment: So in general I have to place my C functions "directory" or "database" inside the package folder? Can I have all my C functions on a shared network drive "X" and my packages on a local drive "C" for example?